# How to create a SpatiaLite Layer in QGIS 3 with Python?

Tags: pyqgis, spatialite

I have an existing SQLITE Database and I want to create several additional geometry Layers with Python.

Within QGIS 2.x I used the following library

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2
```

According to this issue [Pyspatialite in QGIS 3 crash](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16720) QGIS 2.99 does not have the pyspatialite library anymore. With the sqlite3 library there is obviously no spatialite-extension included.

So now I am stuck. Is there another library I can use?

Comment: You can connect to Spatialite databases directly using pysqlite and I would assume also pyspatialite. You can also add spatial data of most types using ogr2ogr. Is there a reason you need to involve QGIS in your workflow?

Comment: Yes, it is part of a QGIS plugin! The whole workflow (creating new polygons, points, topology, etc.) is done in QGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just opened a [PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/5525) to fix this issue in QGIS v3 (on Windows). Remember that this is a dev version.

In the meantime, you could use [this installer](http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.99.0-44-Setup-x86_64.exe) and adjust it by yourself (free software rocks!) after installation. You just need to change [line 602](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/utils.py#L602) of `C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.99\\apps\\qgis-dev\\python\\qgis\\utils.py` by:

```
    ("spatialite", "spatialite_init_ex"),
```

Restart QGIS and now you'll be able to use `sqlite3` connections with `SpatiaLite` support by using the following line from the QGIS Python Console or from your plugin:

```
con = qgis.utils.spatialite_connect("/path/to/your/spatialite_db.sqlite")
```

Now, you can create a new point layer in your database in this way (see [the docs](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html)):

```
cur = con.cursor()
# Run next line if your DB was just created, it may take a while...
cur.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetaData()") 
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE test_geom (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  measured_value DOUBLE NOT NULL);""")
cur.execute("""SELECT AddGeometryColumn('test_geom', 'the_geom',
  4326, 'POINT', 'XY');""")
cur.close()
con.close()
```

This *little* fix also makes db_manager able to open SpatiaLite databases.

Comment: Thank you very much, changing line 602 does the trick! (And of course you are right, it is a dev-version!)

Comment: Great! FYI, Jürgen F. has [commited another change](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/24e636681586e618eeaeb74d5d61a8f0729fe2b7) to make sure SpatiaLite module gets loaded on Windows, which according to him is not happening, even with the change I proposed. So in newer QGIS versions you shouldn't need this code tweak I told you.

Comment: In the last QGIS 2.99 weekly, this works perfectly (without any tweak) :

`import qgis.utils`
...
`con = qgis.utils.spatialite_connect("/path/to/your/spatialite_db.sqlite")`

Comment: Yeap! That's now fixed in QGIS master!

Answer (score 2):

As  Jürgen Fischer said on the bug tracker feed [here](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16720)

> Use sqlite3 instead of pyspatialite for SpatiaLite connections

- get the utils.py file revision https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/repository/revisions/6402160526e3176d1d41f422d6ecab59aa7ac68d
- thank the editor [gcarrillo](https://issues.qgis.org/users/404)